# Error when running ssh: -bash: exec: cd: not found

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Here is the output on the terminal when I run `ssh`, not sure what is wrong.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-86-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

10 packages can be updated.
10 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue May 31 16:08:32 2016 from localhost

-bash: exec: cd: not found

Connection to shageenth-inspiron-3451 closed.
```

Comment: Maybe you should include the exact command you are trying to run?!

Comment: Never put additional information into comments: update your question instead.

Comment: It looks like somewhere in one of your shell startup files (~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile etc.) you are trying to `exec` a `cd` command - which won't work because `cd` is a shell built-in.

Comment: @steeldriver: I believe your comment holds the answer to this question. Could you please convert it to one? Ping me if you want an up-vote.